# Binding query results to UIViewRepresentable in SwiftData

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I use SwiftData to perform a query and retrieve results. I have a property declared like this:

```swift
@Query var allTasks: [Task]
```

Now, I'm attempting to bind the results of this query to a `CustomPicker` within my `ContentView`. The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@Query var allTasks: [Task]
// Other code...

    var body: some View {
        // UIViewRepresentable customPicker
        CustomPicker(data: $allTasks)
        // Rest of the view...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
struct CustomPicker: UIViewRepresentable {
@Binding var current: Task
@Binding var selected: Task
@Binding var data: [Task]

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPickerView {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    picker.dataSource = context.coordinator
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return picker
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPickerView, context: Context) {
    uiView.dataSource = data as? any UIPickerViewDataSource
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(parent: self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    var parent: CustomPicker

    init(parent: CustomPicker) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
...
```

However, it seems like I'm encountering some issues with the binding. Is it possible to directly bind the result obtained from a SwiftData query to a SwiftUI view, especially when using `UIViewRepresentable`?

Comment: Binding is for value types use Bindable for each Task. Query is get-only so you have to rethink your approach Binding is a two-way connection . The only way to get Query to change is via the store/context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe SwiftData only requires Bindable bindings when you want to bind an Observable object property to a SwiftUI View like `Toggle` or `TextField` since you are making a UIKit picker you don't need bingings. You can probably just pass the objects into your picker directly like this:

```
CustomPicker(data: allTasks)
```

And in `CustomPicker: UIViewRepresentable` it's `let allTasks: [Task]` and `updateView` will be called whenever `allTask` is changed. You might need to do your reads of properties inside there too to make sure Observable dependency tracks correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I also need to write into the data and update the UIViewRepresentable. I updated the question with more of my code...

Comment: Since you are dealing with objects you should still just be able to pass them in and get and set the object properties in your custom UIKit picker without any SwiftUI bindings.

Comment: Hey I am dealing with this issue as well. On a very different product/project. My suggestion to you is to make your UIViewRepresentable appear as a sheet. You are going to need a 'central view' that is editable ... you may want to have the user navigate to that view in order to edit/add content. Or make the editable SwiftData view a sheet within your view so the user will be presented that view for editing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

`@Query` is readonly, `@Binding` is two way, by nature you need some logic dealing with that gap.

A way I would do is:

```swift
CustomPicker(data: Binding(get: {allTasks}, set: {_ in }))
```